# Can I move the kitchen to the living room?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens

I am thinking to buy a ground floor flat and am wondering is it possible to move the kitchen to the reception room.  There is room to put it to the right as you walk into the room as an L-shape.  Problem is waster and water pipes.  Could I run the pipes to the bathroom and pump it?  The back boiler is in the reception room, so hot and cold water could come from there potentially.  Help!

[image: Floor Plan]

Comment: Do you have access to the basement beneath the flat? If you have easy access to the underside of your floors, moving the plumbing should be fairly easy (but still won't be "cheap"). If you have to tear up the floors it becomes a much more expensive project and if you have to traverse a structural beam to get to the reception room it becomes even harder. You might be able to run the water pipes up and over the ceiling, but not the drain. Be prepared for a fair amount of electrical work, which could be expensive if the house is old and the new kitchen needs to be brought up to current code.

Comment: Can you physically move it? Certainly. Can you afford to? We can't answer that.

Comment: One thought...leave the kitchen where it is, knock down the walls between the kitchen, hallway, and reception room, and then add an island in the middle. Essentially turning the front of the flat into a large open plan.

Comment: In regards to pumping, it is a possibility, but should be avoided as a solution if gravity drainage is at all possible. Adding the extra complexity, maintenance, chance of things breaking, extended power outages, etc. involved with pumping is not to be taken lightly.

Comment: Thanks everyone that has given some opinions.  Ultimately from reading all of the comments I realise that bashing up the floors is really going beyond sanity.  I should look for a flat which has a bathroom or kitchen next to the reception room if I want to turn the existing kitchen to a bedroom.  The layout here doesn't lend itself to easy reconfiguration.  As it's in an ex-council block and has a lease moving walls presents the uncertainty the freeholder will say no.  All in all a good lesson to pick a property that is easier to modify, problem is they're in short supply.  Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

There is practically nothing that money can't solve, so the answer to your question "can I move the kitchen" is "sure". But it could get very expensive.

In particular, looking at the floor plan it looks like almost all of your plumbing is on the east side of the apartment. Water pipes are pressurized and could be rerouted almost anywhere (e.g. under the floor, in the ceiling) but the sewer lines could get a little more tricky, since they need to slope down to the exit. Also, you will need a vertical vent going *up* from your new kitchen and to the exterior, either through a wall or the roof.

Much of the difficulty will be determined by what kind of access you have above and below your unit (if any).

Comment: Thanks Henry.  Below is no basement, just a concrete floor.  Above is someone else's flat.  The kitchen sink waste is the main issue and rather than throwing the kitchen sink at it, I'll opt to find a different property.  Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Slab construction makes everything far more expensive.  Not bloody likely.

Comment: Just to get a clear picture of what Bryce is implying.  You would need to destroy a channel in the slab, dig a trench, rework the existing piping.  Fill the trench.  Repour the slab.  And that's if everything is _easy_ and goes _smoothly_.  If it is problematic, it is even more expensive.  And that will only move a pipe, you still have the rest of the kitchen to do!